# Using "update preview" for sub-pages in tumblr

Tags: tumblr

In tumblr, when editing my html theme, how do I do the "update preview" for a page other than the root level, for example if I want to see a preview of the post page "myblog.tumblr.com/post/...". The update preview button will only allow me to see my root level "myblog.tumblr.com/" as the links will not work in preview mode.

Right now I need to "save" the changes, go to a random /post/ page I have, then go back to editing, and repeat multiple times. This is not ideal as the changes are pushed to the internet before I am ready to submit them. So I need to somehow do a live preview on my individual posts page.

Comment: You cannot preview the post page unfortunately.

Comment: However the post page will use the same template as the index, so you should be able to see changes (unless they are specific to the post page).